# Can I update my existing iOS app without adding a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have received an email from Apple where it says that Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later and **use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.**

I have couple of old apps in the store (written in Objective-C) where storyboard was not used, we prefer programmatic layout rather then storyboard. My question is:

```
1. Do they remove app from store if we do not update on time?
2. Can i update those apps without adding any storyboard?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add the launch screen storyboard and you'll be fine. You're not forced to rewrite rest of the application.

Comment: 1) Add `UILaunchStoryboardName` (`String`) to your `Info.plist` with the `LaunchScreen` value. 2) Add `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to your project with one view controller scene and make it initial. That's it. It can even contain just one `UIImageView` with your launch screen image.

Answer (score 0):

To your questions:

1. Do they remove app from store if we do not update on time?

I posed this question to Apple support and this was the response:

"These new requirements apply to all apps that are on the store already. To avoid removal, you will need to submit a new version with these requirements met."

2. Can i update those apps without adding any storyboard?

My understanding is that the 'storyboard' requirement pertains only to the launchscreen.

Comment: 1. Rules applied for new apps that will be built after 30th june. Older apps will remain at store as it is.

Comment: What I posted came directly from Apple when specifically questioned about this very thing. Now whether or not Apple acted upon what they indicated would happen, I cannot say, however I stated precisely their response to this question. Down voting my post does not change this fact.